# C++/WinRT handling exceptions from StorageFolder::GetFileAsync

Tags: c++-winrt

When no file exists the app throws an exception which I am unable to catch
In my example code below I create a directory "MyFolder" and save a file "" and save a file "sample.txt" to it.
I then call the function FindFileAsync twice - first using the already created file "sample.txt" which works fine and then using a non-existing file "nofile.txt" which fails with the error
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF94E39D759 in FindFile.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error at memory location.
Is there any solution to this issue.

MainPage.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "MainPage.g.h"

namespace winrt::FindFile::implementation
{
    struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage>
    {
        MainPage();
        Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction FindFileAsync(hstring value);
        Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction GetFolderAsync(hstring const& value);
        Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction CreateFileAsync(hstring const& fname);
        Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction DeletefileAsync(Windows::Storage::StorageFile const & value);

        void ClickHandler(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args);
    private:
        hstring folderDir{ L"MyFolder" };
    };
}

namespace winrt::FindFile::factory_implementation
{
    struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage, implementation::MainPage>
    {
    };
}
```

MainPage.cpp

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.h"
#include "MainPage.g.cpp"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;
using namespace Windows::UI::Popups;

namespace winrt::FindFile::implementation
{
    MainPage::MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainPage::FindFileAsync(hstring value)
    {
        Windows::Storage::StorageFolder storageFolder{ Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current().LocalFolder() };
        StorageFolder sampleFolder{ co_await storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(folderDir, CreationCollisionOption::OpenIfExists) };
        try
        {
            Windows::Storage::StorageFile manifest{ co_await sampleFolder.GetFileAsync(value) };
        }
        catch (winrt::hresult_error msg)
        {
            hstring ms{ msg.message() };
            MessageDialog dlg(ms, L"File Error");
            dlg.ShowAsync();
        }
    }

    Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainPage::GetFolderAsync(hstring const& value)
    {
        Windows::Storage::StorageFolder storageFolder{ Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current().LocalFolder() };
        auto sampleFolder{ co_await storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(value, CreationCollisionOption::OpenIfExists) };
    }

    IAsyncAction MainPage::CreateFileAsync(hstring const& fname)
    {
        Windows::Storage::StorageFolder storageFolder{ Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current().LocalFolder() };
        auto sampleFolder{ co_await storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(folderDir, CreationCollisionOption::OpenIfExists) };
        auto sampleFile{ co_await sampleFolder.CreateFileAsync(L"sample.txt", Windows::Storage::CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting) };
        co_await Windows::Storage::FileIO::WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, L"Swift as a shadow");
    }

    IAsyncAction MainPage::DeletefileAsync(StorageFile const& value)
    {
        co_await value.DeleteAsync();
    }

    void MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
    {
        hstring fname{ L"sample.txt" };
        GetFolderAsync(folderDir);
        CreateFileAsync(fname);
       // The following statement is successful as the file exists
        FindFileAsync(fname);
       // The following ststement throws an exception error 
        FindFileAsync(L"nofile.txt");      
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The code should work as is. It is my understanding that C++ exceptions raised while executing an asynchronous operation are rethrown from the `co_await` operator. This is in line with the documentation  at [Error handling with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/error-handling). Can you produce a [mcve], like a simple command line application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that worked for me.
When the debugger triggers the exception the message includes a checked checkbox. If unchecked and the program is continued to the end the problem is resolved. When run again the error is not triggered and the catch can handle the "file not found". Not sure why the default setting is to trigger the exception.

Answer (score 0):

In C++/WinRT, some exceptions, but not all, force the debugger to pause program execution despite the exception being handled (thrown inside a try block). However, you can resume it by pressing F5 or launching the app without a debugger (CTRL+F5 or via the start menu). I'm not sure whenever this is a bug or intended behavior.